# laravel авторизация роли и прав

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php7, laravel5

я составляю cms на laravel c возможность расширяться через плагины.
Возник вопрос, у меня есть пользователи и каждому можно задавать роли админ , модератор и т.д. так же можно самим создавать роли.
Использую такой код

```
abort_unless(Gate::allows('VIEW_ADMIN_POSTS'), 403);
```

что бы не пускать юзера в неположенный раздел админки.
Вот все права и вид таблицы:

- http://prntscr.com/k618li
- http://prntscr.com/k617tu
- https://prnt.sc/k6181m
- http://prntscr.com/k618d3

проблема в том что если новый плагин создает страницу в админке, он должен назначить ей свои права. К примеру VIEW_SEO и добавить это сразу в таблицу permissions и возможно этот плагин создаст свою роль к примеру seo manager. 
Как это правильный реализовать? или нужно использовать глобальный массив полномочий и синхронизировать с базой данных?